# javascript function expression within function

Tags: javascript, function, function-expression

The working javascript snippet below does not include validation as it is only being used for learning purposes. However, I am not understanding the flow of events after variable 'isBetween' is defined within the buildBoundDetector() function. Why does passing a number through variable 'f' work?

```
function buildBoundDetector( lowerBound, upperBound ) {
    var isBetween = function(number){       
        if(lowerBound <= number && number <= upperBound){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return isBetween;
}

var f = buildBoundDetector( 1, 100 );
f(45);
```

Comment: `return isBetween;`, it returns the function object. So, `f` is the `isBetween` function and you are actually passing `45` to `isBetween`.

Comment: Time to learn about higher order functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function

Answer (score 2):

`buildBoundDetector()` is a function that returns a function. In Javascript, you can assign a function to a variable. That's what `buildBoundDetector()` does. It defines an anonymous function, then assigns it to `isBetween`, then returns `isBetween`. `f` is set to the result of `buildBoundDetector()`, which is that function. Because `f` is a function, you can call it.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, and many other languages, functions can be treated as values. So your first function returns a value which itself is a reference to a function. Then, the returned function value is applied, like any other function, to the argument 45.